# Physical Meaning Of $ dQ/T $ Regarding Clausius Inequality: Is it related to Energy Loss in form of heat or Something Else?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy

What is the physical meaning of term $ dQ/T $ in Clausius Inequality $ dQ/T \le dS $ ?

Physically we can relate entropy to number of microstates of a system, which relates to number of possible arrangements of molecules.

Same way, how can we physically understand the term $ dQ/T $ ?

**My Understanding**:

For a cyclic process, $ dS=0 $. So, $$ dQ/T \le 0 $$ Now since, temperature is always positive, $$ dQ \le 0 $$ 
That means that for a cyclic process, energy in the form of heat can only be lost by a system to the surroundings, otherwise, no energy exchange will happen in the form of heat. It cannot be gained from the surroundings in a cyclic process.

Is my understanding correct? Please also explain the physical meaning of $ dQ/T $, if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not write $dS=0$ for a ***cyclic process*** but rather its closed contour integral $\oint dS = 0$, then you also have $\oint \frac {\delta Q}{T} \le 0$ and from $T>0$ you will get that in a cyclic process you must have somewhere, sometime, at some stage of the cycle $\delta Q < 0$, that is some amount of heat must be rejected to complete the cycle. The integrand $\frac{\delta Q}{T}$ is just the ratio of the heat supplied ${\delta Q}$ at temperature $T$, no more, no less. Its physical meaning is in the Clausius inequality relating it to $dS$.

Comment: To be clear, Is following true? "In a cyclic process, it is impossible that net energy flow in the form of heat, is from surroundings to the system".

Comment: No, while the net heat (absorbed - rejected) can be positive and be converted to work, not all the heat entering the system performing a cycle be converted to work, some of the incoming heat must be rejected. The ratio of the rejected and absorbed heats is never larger than the ratio of the smallest and highest temperatures between the engine is executing the cycle (Carnot's theorem).

Comment: Doesn't $dQ$ represent net heat transfer?

Comment: At each small (infinitesimal) step of the cycle the heat transferred is ${\delta Q}$, in the **full** cycle $\oint {\delta Q}$ is the net heat transfer.

Comment: +1, to me dQ/T says that energy scales with temperature.   a Joule at 300 K is different from a Joule at 1 K.

Comment: That is OK but that is as much the interpretation of the ratio itself as of the verbalization of the Clausius inequality $\oint \frac{\delta Q}{T} \le 0$

Comment: So you are saying that - at some steps, $\delta Q$ will be positive, and at some steps negative, and at some steps zero. But in such a way that $\oint \frac {\delta Q}{T} \le 0$ for a cyclic process - ? ... Also @GeorgeHerold, thanks for the comment, it helped.

Comment: That is precisely.

Comment: @user31748, Entropy is a bit confusing, (at least to me.)  I really liked this.. you have to work through it. http://www.av8n.com/physics/thermo/temperature-ds-de.html